# Simple While True loop and if statements fail to NOT trigger

Tags: python

The relevant code is:

```
while True:
    command = raw_input("Please enter a command: ")
    cls()
    if command == "quit":
        cls()
        quit()
        break
    if command == "add":
        cls()
        problem=add()
        cls()
        if problem==1:
            print "Invalid subject type! Check your spelling, or use the new subject command."
        if problem==2:
            print "Invalid problem type! Please use the *insert new type command here*."
        if problem==3:
            print "Invalid date! Check your spelling or try to express it in another way (i.e. 1/2/14, tomorrow, or in 3 days)."
        if problem==4:
            print "The time you entered was in the past! Hopefully you've already turned in that assignment!"
        if problem==5:
            print "Both the subject and the type are incorrect"
    if command == "print" or "optimize" or "list":
        cls()
        optimize_print()
    if command == "optimize":
        cls()
        optimize_print()
    if command == "remove":
        cls()
        if len(assignments) != 0:
            remove()
        else:
            print "There is nothing to remove"
        cls()
    if command == "open website":
        cls()
        site = raw_input("What website would you like to open? ")
        open_web(site)
    if command == "clear":
        certainty = raw_input("This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to clear all assignments? ")
        if "y" in certainty:
            clear_all()
        else:
            pass
    if command == "start" or "run":
        run_prog()
    if command == "new subject":
        cls()
        sub = raw_input("What subject would you like to add? ")
        for i in subjects:
            if sub.lower() == i.lower():
                print "That subject already exists."
                break
                break
            else:
                pass
        new_subject(sub)
    elif command == "change website" or "new website":
        cls()
        subject_to_add_website = raw_input("What subject would you like to add/change a website for? ")
        change_website(subject_to_add_website)
    if command == "new assignment" or command == "new type" or command == "new assignment type":
        cls()
        ty = raw_input("What assignment type would you like to add? ")
        for i in types:
            if ty.lower() == i.lower():
                print "That assignment type already exists."
                break
                break
            else:
                pass
        new_type(ty)
```

We have a scheduling program in python 2.7 that uses a while True loop to prompt for new inputs once a given function is done running.  All of a sudden without us being aware of any significant changes being made within the while loop the program now executes ALL of the if statements even if you input a string that doesn't match any of them.  Am I missing something obvious here? (I should add this is being run in console and worked previously but now fails on various macs and pcs)

Comment: Where is `run_prog()` defined? What does it do? This will be executed every time.

Comment: `command == "start" or "run"` should be `command in ("start", "run")`.

Comment: run_prog() just goes through a list of assignments and tells the user to do them. Why will it be run every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your if statements containing `or` will run regardless of `command`'s value. This is because a string literal is evaluated as `True`

The condition `if command == "start" or "run"` evaluates the value of `command` first, then evaluates the "truthiness" of the string `run`. This condition is always satisfied and will always run the code following it.

This should be changed to:

```
if command == "start" or command =="run":
    do.something()
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparisions like

```
command == "print" or "optimize" or "list"
```

will always evaluate to `True`.  Python evaluates this as

```
(command == "print") or bool("optimize") or bool("list") # non-empty strings evaluate to True
```

Here is how to correct your code:

```
command == "print" or command == "optimize" or command == "list"
```

The pythonic way of writing this is:

```
command in ("print", "optimize", "list")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing:

```
command == "start" or "run"
```

You should type:

```
command == "start" or command == "run"
```

Because in the first case the or "run" will unconditionally evaulate to True and hence will be executed every time